# How to set the position of UIButton center vertically (swift)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a `UIView` then a `UIButton` in it, i want my `UIButton` to be vertically center. How can I do that, so that it will be the basis of my other button for auto-layout

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please?

Comment: I cant post an image yet. I have three buttons in a view, I want to set the "X displacement" of my second button to centre so that it will be the basis for the two other buttons.

Comment: are you using story board?

Comment: @ArslanAsim yes I am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using xib or storyboard.
Following these steps

1- Drag Button on your view. (you can place it any where in view for now)

2- At bottom you will see 3 buttons as in image

[image]

3- click on left most button (make sure you have selected button)[image]

4- Under update frame select items of new Constraints

5- Select Add 2 Constraints.

Now you'r button is vertically and horizontally center in view .